# POI Java - Numeric Cell with Decimals

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm having a lot of problems with numeric formats in a Cell with POI.

I need to print in the cell 11 decimals for a number and also that the cell has a numeric format to make the sum when you select the data

And I have this code:

```
private void writeDecimal(HSSFRow row, Double data, int position) {
    String pattern = "#.0000000000";
    HSSFCell celda = row.createCell(position);
    CellStyle styleDecimal = styles.get(ITEM_DECIMAL); // Font and alignment
    styleDecimal.setDataFormat(libro.getCreationHelper().createDataFormat().getFormat(pattern));
    celda.setCellStyle(styleDecimal);
    celda.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
    celda.setCellValue(data);
}
```

But the result always print less decimal because Excel rounds the number:

[image: Decimal Problem with POI]

If I convert the `Double` to `String`, prints the 11 decimals but it doesn't make the sum if I select all the numbers.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the xlsx file select the column , right click on cell -> Format cells...->custom->type = 0.00000000000 click ok.

now whatever you will write on that cell, it will print on that format and if you select also it will show the sum.

by code

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

    import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormat;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;


    public class ChangeXlxsDataFormat {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
                Sheet sheet = (Sheet) wb.createSheet("format sheet");
                CellStyle style;
                DataFormat format = wb.createDataFormat();
                Row row;
                Cell cell;
                short rowNum = 0;
                short colNum = 0;

                row = sheet.createRow(rowNum);
                cell = row.createCell(colNum);

                style = wb.createCellStyle();
                        row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
                cell = row.createCell(colNum);

                style = wb.createCellStyle();
                style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("0.00000000000"));
                cell.setCellStyle(style);
                cell.setCellValue(5.12345678908);
                row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
                cell = row.createCell(colNum);
                cell.setCellValue(2.12345678908);
                FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("test.xls");
                wb.write(fileOut);
                fileOut.close();


        }

    }
```

Comment: I don't want to do it manually, I need to make it through POI so that the receiver of the Excel does not have to make any changes...

Comment: are you generating the new xlsx file programatically every time?

Comment: Yes, everytime I generate a new file with new data

Comment: check the code i have added , it will help you to create the file and change the format for column

Comment: Thanks!! So the problem is the CELL_TYPE? If I avoid it and I only put the DataFormat it works!

Comment: yes, but i have added the full code so that it can help others in future. thanks for accepting the answer

Comment: DataFormat is is applied to all the data at the Excel Book? If I need a number with 3 decimals and another with 11 decimals only gets the last one

Comment: before writing the data to column repeat style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("0.000")); again

Comment: if this solution is working for you please accept the answer

Answer (score 3):

This code snippet doesn't contain `celda.setCellStyle( styleDecimal )`. Is it missing in the real code too? Add it.

**Edit:**

Here is a simple example using your function. It works well.

```
private static HSSFWorkbook workbook;

public static void main( String args[] ) throws IOException {
  workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
  HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet( "sheet" );
  HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow( 0 );
  writeDecimal( row, 0.0781013, 0 );
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( "workbook.xls", false );
  workbook.write( fos );
  fos.close();
}

private static void writeDecimal( HSSFRow row, Double data, int position ) {
  String pattern = "#.0000000000";
  HSSFCell celda = row.createCell(position);
  CellStyle styleDecimal = workbook.createCellStyle(); // Font and alignment
  styleDecimal.setDataFormat(workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat(pattern));
  celda.setCellStyle(styleDecimal);
  celda.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
  celda.setCellValue(data);
}
```

What was the problem in your code? I don't know. Your style definitely wasn't applied to the page: zeros shouldn't be rendered with "#".

Comment: Sorry, wrong snippet, it's added in the real code, I just edited the question, thanks!